# session was not created by this client - MongoDB, Golang

Tags: mongodb, go

I am trying to creat transaction in MongoDB with Golang and Iris. Problem is that transaction did not accept iris context and Con, I don't know why this thing happened. Can you tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Main.go Using Iris

```
func main() {
app := iris.New()
app.Logger().SetLevel("debug")
app.Use(recover.New())
app.Use(logger.New())

// Resource: http://localhost:8080
app.Get("/", func(ctx iris.Context) {
    ctx.JSON(iris.Map{"message": "Welcome to Woft Bank"})
})

// API endpoints
router.SetRoute(app)

app.Listen(PORT)}
```

Router

```
func SetRoute(app *iris.Application) {
userRoute := app.Party("/user")
{
    userRoute.Post("/register", middleware.UserValidator, controller.CreateUser)
    userRoute.Get("/detail", middleware.UserValidator, controller.GetUserBalanceWithUserID)
    userRoute.Patch("/transfer", middleware.TransferValidator, controller.Transfer)
}}
```

Transacion function (session was not created by this client)

```
func Transfer(ctx iris.Context) {
senderID := ctx.URLParam("from")
receiverID := ctx.URLParam("to")
amount, _ := strconv.ParseInt(ctx.URLParam("amount"), 10, 64)
session, err := Config.DB().StartSession()
if err != nil {
    handleErr(ctx, err)
    return
}
defer session.EndSession(ctx)

callback := func(sessCtx mongo.SessionContext) (interface{}, error) {
    upsert := false
    after := options.After
    opt := options.FindOneAndUpdateOptions{
        ReturnDocument: &after,
        Upsert:         &upsert,
    }
    sender := Models.User{}
    filter := bson.M{"username": senderID}
    update := bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"balance": -amount}}
    //FindOneAndUpdate did not accept sessCtx
    err := UserCollection.FindOneAndUpdate(sessCtx, filter, update, &opt).Decode(&sender)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    if sender.Balance < 0 {
        return nil, errors.New("sender's balance is not enough")
    }

    filter = bson.M{"username": receiverID}
    update = bson.M{"$inc": bson.M{"balance": +amount}}
    _, err = UserCollection.UpdateOne(sessCtx, filter, update)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return sender, nil
}
result, err := session.WithTransaction(ctx, callback)
if err != nil {
    handleErr(ctx, err)
    return
}
response(result, "success", ctx)}
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving?

Comment: Only thing that "UserCollection.FindOneAndUpdate(sessCtx, filter, update, &opt).Decode(&sender)" return is error with message "session was not created by this client"

Comment: You haven't posted enough code, but it's likely `UserCollection` and `session` are created using different mongo clients. They must be created using a single, same client. E.g. if you acquire a `db` using `Config.DB()`, you must use this `db` instance to create the session and acquire the collection. Then you won't get this error. If this doesn't solve your issue, post a [mcve].